# XCode 7 debugger not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, debugging

I Convert my project to iOS 9 in XCode 7.

And i noticed that i get a lot of warning like this:

```
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSArray
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)UIView
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSString
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSNumber
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSObject
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)UIWebView
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)UIView
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSObject
warning: Could not resolve external type c:@S@_NSRange
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSURL
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSBundle
warning: Could not resolve external type c:objc(cs)NSException
```

From what i read in need to set `GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS` to NO and this will remove this warnings, and it really work.But now the debugger don't stop in any break-point that i set. When i set `GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS` to YES the debugger work fine.

Any idea?

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your "Build settings" try setting these parameters:

```
Enable Clang Module Debugging = NO
Debug Information Format = DWARF with dSYM
Precompile Prefix Header = NO
```

And rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when you have a Xcode 6 project updated to 7. The short answer is to change the Debug Information Format to "DWARF", on the target, for the Debug configuration only.

- Go to Build Settings and search for Debug Information Format
- Change the Debug setting from "DWARF with dSYM File" to "DWARF"
- Leave the Release setting at "DWARF with dSYM File"

This is safe because you don't need  dSYM files for Debug builds