# Xcode 7.3.1 '<could not resolve type>' in debug console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

I have a problem with debug mode in my Xcode 7.3.1, when I want print something in console it prints "" or even if I want go deeper in object details I can't expand anything:

[image]

What is interesting I have everything working if I want see something inside one of pod library details:

[image]

Thank you for any help ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863593/xcode-7-debugger-not-working Check this might help you (?)

Comment: No, it didn't help me ;/

Comment: i facing this broblem too

Comment: anyone can help us?

Comment: see my answer below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer, my problem was in `Project-Bridging-Header` file.
I had before:

```
#import "DeepLinkKit.h"
```

and now I have:

```
#import <DeepLinkKit/DeepLinkKit.h>
```

and everything is printing's fine ;)

Comment: I was also facing same issue and your solution worked for me. Thanks buddy.